# How can I make an invisible wall in Webots?

Tags: webots

I need to create an invisible wall in Webots but I don't know how to do it. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create an invisible wall, you can simply create a [Solid](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/solid) node with no `children` field, so that it is invisible, no `physics` field, so that it is attached to the static world and a [Box](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/box) node as a `boundingObject`, so that collision detection will be based on this box:

```js
Solid {
  translation 0 0 1
  rotation 0 0 1 0
  name "my invisible wall"
  boundingObject Box {
    size 0.2 4 2
  }
}
```

The above [Solid](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/solid) node will act as an invisible wall located at the center of the world, with a height of 2 meters, a length of 4 meters and a thickness of 20 cm. You will be able to change its `translation` and `rotation` fields to move it around and rotate it.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*